# When can I play in Hardcore mode?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've heard that there are some limitations on being able to create/play hardcore characters in Diablo 3.

What are the parameters (if any) that need to be met to create a hardcore character? Can I jump in straight away with a hardcore character?

Comment: My original title was funnier :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must reach level 10 with any character before Hardcore is unlocked. You do not need to *keep* a character at level 10 however, as deleting all of your level 10 softcore characters will not remove your ability to play hardcore.

[Quoth Blue:](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4877537721#4)

> Level 10 is when we open access to create hardcore characters. We want
>   players to have a general idea of how to play before giving hardcore a
>   try. Experienced players will easily reach this level in a few hours,
>   so we think this makes for a good balance.

Comment: Wow, I was thinking that this was just for Betas