# Can I have only hardcores?

Tags: diablo-iii

At level 10[¹](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66198/12936) you can create a Hardcore hero. My friend ask me this and I didn't know how to answer him.

> If I level up my barbarian until level 10 and create a hardcore, Can I
>   delete my soft-core barbarian and have an account with hardcore only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When can I play in Hardcore mode?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66194/when-can-i-play-in-hardcore-mode)

Comment: @Bora ?? This question has nothing to do with the one you linked.

Comment: Well, not the question itself, perhaps, but the @RavenDreamer's answer contains the answer to your question.

Comment: @Bora True, but the question itself don't. I believe we shouldn't close questions because in other question, may or may not contain the correct answer for this. The question is not duplicated, the answer contain more information than its needed to answer the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just try it out: Create a level 1 hardcore dummy, then try to delete your non-hardcore character. Nothing will stop you from doing so.